# ActivityForResult To Only Get A JPEG

Tags: android, mime-types, android-intent, android-image, android-gallery

Hey everybody,
I'm writing a small social networking app, and one of the features I included is the ability to upload a picture to a server to be used as your "profile picture". I did this by starting an ActivityForResult with this intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
System.out.println("STARTED IT HERE");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
```

This lets the user choose between getting an image URI from whatever accepts this Intent (Gallery and Astro by me). I have code that handles everything, and it all works (other than an issue with an outOfMemoryException when I pick the image from the gallery, but that's for a different topic :) ). My question is, how can I say something like:

```
intent.setType("image/jpeg");
```

because I only want users to upload jpegs?

Thanks so much in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You just want to limit people to picking jpg style files?

How about this?

`Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

pickPhoto.setType("image/*.jpg");`

Sorry had to edit, I copied the wrong two lines from my app. Went one line to high. This is what I meant.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried that already but I shall try again and let you know

Comment: When I tried that, the stock gallery didn't display anything (though I'm 100% positive that i have jpgs in there), and Astro displayed all files that I have

Comment: wrong action - you have to use MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE